# Accessing Codeigniter in BitNami Wamp stack

Tags: codeigniter, wamp, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, bitnami

I've just downloaded and installed Bitnami's Wamp Stack 5.4.16.0 which includes Codeigniter on a machine running Windows 7 Enterprise. The installation was successful and both Apache and MySQL servers are running, as per the green ball and the "running" status in the BitNanmi console.

I checked BitNami's wiki at http://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/PHP_Frameworks/CodeIgniter and tried following the steps to enable the sample application, but it doesn't work because:

a) the line "Include "installdir/frameworks/codeigniter/conf/codeigniter.conf"" doesn't exist in the http config file

b) when I add the line "Include "installdir/frameworks/codeigniter/conf/codeigniter.conf"", changing the installdir to my installation directory, the file codeigniter.conf is missing on the folder indicated on the path. In fact, I can't find the file codeigniter.conf anywhere

As a result, I can't access codeigniter from my localhost/codeigniter as suggested in the wiki.

Do you guys know how to run Codeigniter on BitNami's Wamp stack? And if yes, can you let me know how to do it?

Many thanks in advance, Dinis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys,

this is a misconfiguration in BitNami and the guys at their forum were awesomely quick replying back. Here are the steps to make it work:

1. Go to your installation directory and start manager-windows.exe
2. Click "Configure" button
3. Click "Open Conf File" button and this opened the httpd.conf file
4. Add the line Include "C:/BitNami/wamp/frameworks/codeigniter/conf/httpd-prefix.conf" and save the changes
5. Restart Apache in the application manager

Original thread: http://answers.bitnami.com/questions/14148/accessing-codeigniter-in-bitnami-wamp-stack

Answer (score 0):

Another thing mentioned today is to fix this by going to

/Applications/mampstack-5.4.16-0/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf

and uncommenting the line:

Include "/Applications/mampstack-5.4.16-0/frameworks/codeigniter/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"

Hope they get the docs updated soon.